# function pointer : why is (*fptr)(6,7) same as (fptr)(6,7) , if the function is add(int , int )

Tags: c, function, pointers

In `function pointers`,

Why is `(*fptr)(int a, int b)` is same as `(fptr)(int a, int b)` if the function pointer is assigned to add function?

```
int (*fptr)(int ,int) = add; 
while add(int a , int b) returns sum of two numbers.
```

Comment: Please post proper code that demonstrates the question. What you have written are two different types (one is a function type, the other is a function pointer type). And the question title is different from the question body.

Comment: Now to completely twist your mind: what about `(****fptr)(6, 7)`?

Comment: @Ayush: "improved" is a strong word...

Comment: You do not need for dereference because function  and  pointer to function both they are handled as a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

C doesn't have function **objects**, so it makes no sense to dereference a function pointer. Therefore, when a function pointer is dereferenced, it is (with some exceptions) immediately turned back into a pointer to function.

### References

[n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the final public draft of the current C standard):

> #### 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators
>
> 4. The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a **function designator**; [...]

...

> #### 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> 4. A **function designator** is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘**pointer to function returning type**’’.

Answer (score 0):

**6.5.2.2 Function calls 5**

> If the expression that denotes the called function has type pointer to
>   function returning an object type, the function call expression has
>   the same type as that object type, and has the value determined as
>   specified in 6.8.6.4.

Comment: This is not very useful for a beginner...

Comment: I think it's grounds for why the show.