# Large unexpected u16_t buf

Tags: c++, c, pointers, c-libraries

I have C function that calls pointer to function (with pointer to buf and size of buf)

```
printf("------------------------------\n");
printf("lengh of DATA_output = %zu\n", p->tot_len);
(*myStr.OnSendData)(buf, p->tot_len);
printf("------------------------------\n");
```

pointer to function defined like

```
typedef void (*pOnSendData)(void *buf, u16_t len);
```

Then my real c++ class method gets it through that pointer:

```
void Someclass::myPOnSendData(void *buf, u16_t len) {
std::cout << " Someclass::mypOnSendData len = " << (int)len << std::endl;
//Do something
}
```

The problem is that `len` of `buf` is pretty large.

output is :

```
------------------------------
lengh of DATA_output = 42
------------------------------

Someclass::myPOnSendData len = 50512
```

How could that be?

Comment: Why do people still think C/C++ is a language?

Comment: @ValentinMercier Over my head.  What is C/C++, if not a language?

Comment: `void (*)(void *, size_t)` is incompatible with `void (*)(void *, u16_t)`

Comment: sorry, both are u16_t . Fixed in question

Comment: How is `myPOnSendData` declared in the class? Is it static?

Comment: @Fiddling, C and C++ are not the same language, and never were: from day one, there were valid C programs that could not be compiled by a C++ compiler, and obviously the other way around.

Comment: C/C++ is used cus there is a 'C' lib and I need C++ application. Is that a problem? Please, stop HOLY WARS. Help me with this thing..  please.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Oh, I see. ValentinMercier is saying C and C++ are not the same language.  I thought he was saying C and C++ are not languages at all.  Sorry.

Comment: @RedCollarPanda, maybe consider `[c-libraries]` for this purpose. Tried that for you.

Comment: @ValentinMercier C/C++ is not a language. They are two different languages, and this question is about interfacing between them. Your edit (which I reverted) completely changed the meaning.

Comment: myPOnSendData is not static

Comment: @ValentinMercier, sorry for my mistake - my brain is boiling...

Comment: what is the type of p<-tot_len?

Comment: you don't need to dereference a function pointer because it'll be done automatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508504/function-pointer-why-is-fptr6-7-same-as-fptr6-7-if-the-function-is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that `myPOnSendData` is not a static member function, but you are trying to assign a pointer to it into a C pointer-to-function. This won't work because C-style pointers to functions do not support non-static member function.

If you change the function to be static, it will be compatible with the pointer type.

Note that since the types are currently incompatible, you probably got an error message when trying to assign the function pointer, and had to perform a cast to get around it. Don't do this, as you are just hiding the error rather than solving it.